# google AI model serving vs kfsering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ai

We are going to do model serving infrastructure. I am comparing [Google AI Prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/overview) and [kfserving](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/serving/kfserving/). But I cannot find enough documents about the features of google ai serving and how it is implemented.

It seems that `gcloud ai-platform versions create` can create model version resource and start serving, which is the only point I can find.

I have three questions:

1, what is relationship between google ai serving and kfserving?

2, how `gcloud ai-platform versions create` works?

3, as for the features of google ai serving, do google ai serving provide all feature such as canary rollout, explainers, monitoring, etc listed in https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/serving/overview/?

Answer (score 1):

The document you shared contains extensive information about [Google AI Platform Prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/overview#how_it_works). In summary, it is a hosted service in GCP where you don't need to manage the infrastructure. You just deploy your model and a new REST endpoint will be available for you to start sending predictions via SDK or API.

- Supports multiple frameworks:

  - TensorFlow
  - scikit-learn
  - XGBoost
  - Pytorch
  - Custom Docker containers (soon)
- Support GPUs
- Model versions
- Online and Batch prediction
- Logging and Monitoring
- Multiple Regions
- REST API

Answer to your questions:

1. KFServing you need to manage your own K8s/KubeFlow infrastructure.
   Kubeflow supports two model serving systems that allow multi-framework model serving: KFServing and Seldon Core. 
   AI Platform Service you don't manage the infrastructure, nor need K8s/KF, you simply deploy your models and GCP takes care of the infra.
2. `gcloud ai-platform versions create` will deploy a VM(s) in Google Cloud where based on the settings (Runtime) and Framework all the dependencies will be installed automatically, also all you need to load your model will be installed so you can have access to a REST API.
3. Canary can be implemented used with different Models and versions, it may depend on routing your predictions. Check the [What If tool](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#adjust_prediction_outputs_for_the_what-if_tool) and Model [logging](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/overview#prediction_logging).

Answer (score 0):

1. Google AI Platform can be used to manage the following stages in the ML workflow:

**-Train an ML model on your data:**

Train model
Evaluate model accuracy
Tune hyperparameters

**-Deploy your trained model.**

**-Send prediction requests to your model:**

Online prediction
Batch prediction (for TensorFlow only)

**-Monitor the predictions on an ongoing basis.**

**-Manage your models and model versions.**

2. KFServing enables serverless inferencing on Kubernetes and provides performant, high abstraction interfaces for common machine learning (ML) frameworks like TensorFlow, XGBoost, scikit-learn, PyTorch, and ONNX to solve production model serving use cases.